# How to use Gulp with Razor and Layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, gulp

What is the best way to use Gulp in MVC template files? The problem is that my layout.cshtml files contain links to JavaScript files, gulp would need to modify these files to point at the optimized minified files. The problem is that I cannot see how I can use gulp to modify these files to point at the optimized files for debug and release because the source file would need to be the destination file and the mechanism would need to work with TFS.  The best idea I have had would be to use the bundling mechanism. Before investing time into this I want to see if there are simpler alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, please let me know if there is a better way of doing this.
I ran:

```
 Install-Package System.Web.Optimization.HashCache
```

Then I modified the BundleConfig.cs to include

```
var myBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundle_virtual_path").Include("~/Scripts/CombinedFile.js");
myBundle.Transforms.Add(new HashCacheTransform());
bundles.Add(myBundle);
```

Then I modified _Layout.cshtml to include

```
 @{    
    if (HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)
    {
        <script src = "~/Scripts/App/File1.js" ></script>
        <script src = "~/Scripts/App/File2.js" ></script>
    }
     else
    {
         @Scripts.Render("~/bundle_virtual_path");
    }
 }
```

In this way I use bundles to do cache busting on the output of a gulp script which can be attached to the before build event in the Task Runner Explorer. For completeness here is a extremely simple funtion that generates the CombinedFile.js in this sample

```
gulp.task('myTest', function () {
    return gulp.src(['Scripts/App/File1.js', 'Scripts/App/File2.js'])
     .pipe(concat('CombinedFile.js'))
     .pipe(gulp.dest('Scripts'));
});
```

Gulp file listening functions should be attached to the Project Open event

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this without bringing .net bundling into the picture.

using the gulp plugin gulp-rev and the nuget package called FileTagger

gulp.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
     rimraf = require("rimraf"),
     concat = require("gulp-concat"),
     cssmin = require("gulp-cssmin"),
     uglify = require("gulp-uglify"),
     filter = require("gulp-filter"),
     rename = require("gulp-rename"),
     rev = require('gulp-rev');

var paths = {};
paths.jsSource = mainBowerFiles();
paths.baseReleaseFolder = "app";
///these names get alter by rev()
paths.baseJSReleaseFile = "site.min.js";

gulp.task("min:js", function () {
var jsFilter = filter('**/*.js', { restore: true });
return gulp
    .src(paths.jsSource)
    .pipe(jsFilter)
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(concat(paths.baseReleaseFolder + "/" + paths.baseJSReleaseFile))
    .pipe(rev())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("."))
    .pipe(jsFilter.restore);
});
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>App</title>   
@FileTagger.Render.Script("~/app/site-*.min.js")
</head>
    <body>@RenderBody()</body>
</html>
```